# AngularJS $scope variable change in .then() unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

I'm trying to unit test a function within my controller but am unable to get a `$scope` variable to be testable. I'm setting the variable in my controller's `.then()` and want to unit test to make sure this is set appropriately when it hits the .then block.

My test controller code:

```
function submit() {
    myService.submit().then(function(responseData){
        if(!responseData.errors) {
            $scope.complete = true;
            $scope.details = [
                {
                    value: $scope.formattedCurrentDate
                },
                {
                    value: "$" + $scope.premium.toFixed(2)
                },  
            ];
        } else {
            $scope.submitError = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Where this service call goes is irrelevant. It will return JSON with `action: 'submitted', 'response' : 'some response'`. The .then() checks if errors are present on responseData, and if not it should set some details. These $scope.details are what I'm trying to test in my unit test below:

```
it('should handle submit details', function () {
    var result;
    var premium = 123.45;
    var formattedCurrentDate = "2016-01-04";
    var promise = myService.submit();
    mockResponse = {
        action: 'submitted',
        response: 'some response'
    };
    var mockDetails = [
        {
            value: formattedCurrentDate
        },
        {
            value: "$"+ premium.toFixed(2)
        }   
    ];

    //Resolve the promise and store results
    promise.then(function(res) {
        result = res;
    });
    //Apply scope changes
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(mockDetails).toEqual(submitController.details);
});
```

I'm receiving an error that $scope.details is undefined. I'm not sure how to make the test recognize this $scope data changing within the controller.

Before each and other functions in my unit test:

```
function mockPromise() {
    return {
        then: function(callback) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(mockResponse);
            }
        }
    }
}

beforeEach(function() {
    mockResponse = {};
    module('myApp');

    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.service('myService', function() {
            this.submit = jasmine.createSpy('submit').and.callFake(mockPromise);
        });
    });

    inject(function($injector) {
        $q = $injector.get('$q');
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        myService = $injector.get('myService');

        submitController = $controller('myController', { $scope: $scope, $q : $q, myService: myService});
    });
});
```

How do I resolve the promise within my unit test so that I can $scope.$digest() and see the $scope variable change?

Comment: Same problem here, driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You should look how to test promises with jasmine 
http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine_Provide_Spy/

using a `callFake` would do what you try to mock

```
spyOn(myService, 'submit').and.callFake(function() {
  return {
    then: function(callback) { return callback(yourMock); }
  };
});
```